# Installing piwik with symfony2

Tags: symfony, installation, matomo

I would like to install piwik for my symfony2 project.

I haven't found any documentation about this use case.
What would be the best practice ?

Shoul i install it in /web/piwik ?

Comment: You could use a bundle (http://knpbundles.com/KnpLabs/KnpPiwikBundle) or integrate it yourself if you feel comfortable enough doing it.

Comment: Does the bundle install piwik or just integrate the javascript code of piwik ? There is no other doc than the link you suggested and the bundle is not maintained anymore... :(

Comment: There is a second one that seems to have been recently updated: http://knpbundles.com/jirafe/AnalyticsTrackerBundle I am not familiar at all with piwik but when I use Google analytics, I just add the javascript code in a `base.html.twig` template from where all other templates derive.

Comment: Piwik is all local web analytics, so you need to install piwik then include the javascript code. The last part is easy, but the first is my question.

Comment: I just went through the documentation. Do you really want piwik to be part of your website? You can install it on a second website (let's say analytics.yourwebsite.com) and then simply use the Javascript on your Symfony2 website.

Comment: I finally came to the same conclusion. Thanks for the effort. One of us can give an answer to the question that i will validate ;)

Comment: Post an answer with your complete solution! :)

Answer (score 2):

The answer i found is from [this website](http://library.linode.com/web-applications/analytics/piwik/ubuntu-12.04-precise-pangolin).

The main steps are :

- create a database user and so for piwik

  ```
  mysql -u root -p
  create database piwik;
  CREATE USER 'piwik'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '12345';
  GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON piwik.* TO 'piwik' IDENTIFIED BY '12345';
  ```
- create a virtual host for piwik
- install piwik (i just needed to install pdo_mysql)
- integrate js code of piwik in your `base.html.twig` in symfony2